# Use connected app that exists in production to connect to sandbox

Tags: sandbox, connected-apps

I have the following scenario and would like to discuss if this is possible at all. Some customer wants to do some tests in a sandbox. It's the same org as the prod environment. We have a perfectly working connected app in the prod environment i also have a valid jwt and the source infromation used to create the jwt. However i don't have a working user. I only have this information and the sandbox url and sandbox name. Is there any way to access data in the sandbox?
So far i tried setting the aud, sub and oAuth2Endpoint like this:

```
oAuth2Endpoint="https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"
aud="https://test.salesforce.com"
sub="app.integration@crm.company.com.sandboxname."
```

I also tried a couple of other variations like using the sandbox name and url for the oAuth2Endpoint and aud. At the end i always get the following error:

```
{'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': "user hasn't approved this consumer"}
```

I know about this "solution": https://mannharleen.github.io/2020-03-03-salesforce-jwt/
However as far as i understand i need a working user for this, right?
Can anybody provide some insight if there can be a solution at all or if i need more information like a user for the sandbox. Thanks